# Undoing `git checkout -- [filename(s)]`

Tags: git

How does one undo  `git checkout -- [filename(s)]`?

I've tried looking here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things

Meant to unstage, not revert...

Comment: I'm pretty sure unstage is `git reset HEAD [filename(s)]`. Git tells you what to do when you run `git status` -> `Changes to be committed: (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)`

Comment: Ah, you weren't asking how to unstage...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+checkout